# Selenium Optimize getVisibleElement (when element is not present)

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, fluent

I am using jBehave/Selenium for automation testing.

Now I use the following code to get visible elements on the page;

```
public WebElement getVisibleElement( final By by, final WebElement parentElement, int timeoutValue, TimeUnit timeoutPeriod, int pollingInterval, TimeUnit pollingPeriod ) {
       return fluentWait(timeoutValue, timeoutPeriod, pollingInterval, pollingPeriod).until( new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>(){
                public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                    try{
                        WebElement element = parentElement.findElement(by);
                        if ( element.isDisplayed() ) {
                            return element;
                        } else {
                            return null;
                        }
                    } catch( NoSuchElementException e ) {}

                    return null; 
                }
        } );
    }
```

Now the issue is, if the element is not present on page, Selenium spends a lot of time trying to find it on page. 
Is there any way by which I can optimize the code, so that it does no spend a long time in such cases?

Comment: Same topic is here, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-developers/kS1YCoMMc0U

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think you should not check the presence of element by calling findElement and catching potential exception. It's better to use findElements and check the list size

```java
public WebElement getElementIfPresent(By locator) {
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(locator);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if(!elements.isEmpty()) {
        return elements.get(0);
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem is that WebDriver will wait implicitly for the elements to appear. So before you execute the above code you may want to cut that time by setting implicit waits time to lower value. This needs to be dobe before you do any lookup of an element that potentially may not exist. You then need to restore the original implicit wait value, otherwise it may impact the stability of remaining tests.

In the end you just check for visibility using `isDisplayed()` just as you did it in your example.

Comment: Thx a lot...I just wanted to understand where exactly should I place the 2nd part of the code i.e. implicitlyWait ....Should it be just before the check for ....if(!elements.isEmpty()) { }

Comment: No, not before isEmpty(). It needs to be checked before you attempt to look up an element in other words before calling findElement. I've edited my answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

even a more optimized solution - is to use the `findElements(locator).size()`...

```
    /**
     * Private method that acts as an arbiter of implicit timeouts of sorts.. sort of like a Wait For Ajax method.
     */
    private WebElement waitForElement(By by) {
        int attempts = 0;
        int size = driver.findElements(by).size();

        while (size == 0) {
            size = driver.findElements(by).size();
            if (attempts == MAX_ATTEMPTS) fail(String.format("Could not find %s after %d seconds",
                                                             by.toString(),
                                                             MAX_ATTEMPTS));
            attempts++;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000); // sleep for 1 second.
            } catch (Exception x) {
                fail("Failed due to an exception during Thread.sleep!");
                x.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (size > 1) System.err.println("WARN: There are more than 1 " + by.toString() + " 's!");

        return driver.findElement(by);
    }
```

The way this is built, is you'd call this before operating on it.  Something like,

```
WebElement myElement = waitforElement(By.cssSelector("input#someInput"));
myElement.sendKeys("something");
```

This is a proven solution that i've tested and actively use in production-grade regression testing systems.

Comment: I don't see any benefit in this method over `WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10, 1000).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#someElement")));`